# Configure metro.config of yarn workspaces monorepo containing multiple apps and packages

Tags: react-native, monorepo, yarn-workspaces

How can I configure the `metro.config.js` of a monorepo containing multiple apps (in `<root>/apps/`) and packages (in `<root>/packages/`) to work for all apps in the monorepo? Each app has its own `yarn workspace` defined in the root `package.json`.

My current `metro.config.js` is:

```
const path = require("path");
const {getDefaultConfig} = require("metro-config");

module.exports = (async () => {
  const {
    resolver: {sourceExts, assetExts},
  } = await getDefaultConfig(__dirname);

  return {
    projectRoot: path.resolve(__dirname),
    watchFolders: [path.resolve(__dirname)],
    transformer: {
      getTransformOptions: async () => ({
        transform: {
          experimentalImportSupport: false,
          inlineRequires: false,
        },
      }),
      babelTransformerPath: require.resolve("react-native-svg-transformer"),
    },
    resolver: {
      assetExts: assetExts.filter(ext => ext !== "svg"),
      sourceExts: [...sourceExts, "svg"]
    },
  };
})();
```

However, this setup seems to not load the node_modules packages of the apps (`<root>/apps/<app-name>/node_modules`), giving me an seemingly unrelated error (but after I move the config to the app folder, the app runs - but does not work, because it uses `react-native-svg-transformer`, which forces me to have `metro.config.js` in the monorepo root, otherwise it does not work).

Comment: I could be wrong here, but have you tried using `nohoist` to manage the location of `react-native-svg-transformer`?